# NSException error when using Python, Flask, HTML

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2, nsexception

so I making a website to output projections of nba games. I currently have a dictionary with all of the team logo paths as the key value in the dictionary and the percentages of winning the game as the value. The dictionary called projec_d looks like this:

```
{
 'static/Portland Trail Blazers.png': '0.20%',
 'static/Milwaukee Bucks.png': '99.80%', 
 'static/New Orleans Pelicans.png': '36.40%', 
 'static/Phoenix Suns.png': '63.60%'
}
```

in my app.py script the code that uses this dictionary is:

```
return render_template('home.html', projec_d=projec_d)
```

The code for the home.html file that should for now just output the logo and the percentage is this:

```
 {% for item in projec_d.items() %}
      <h3> {{ item }} </h3>
 {% endfor %}
```

I have also tried:

```
 {% for key in project_d.keys() %}
      <img src="{{ key }}" alt="">
      <h3> {{ project_d[key] }} </h3>
 {% endfor %}
```

None seem to work. The error message is very strange. It is a longer than the photo I attached, here is the error: [NSException error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ByzMu.png)

Comment: No idea how to read that error: try `{% for _, item in projec_d.items() %}` for the first example

Comment: Tried it, doesn't work :/

Answer (score 0):

You are using the path to the logo as the key for the percentage.
A better way to do this would be a list of dictionaries:

```
teams = [
    {
        'logo': 'path/to/logo.png',
        'percentage': 53.5%
    },
    {
        'logo': 'path/to/logo2.png',
        'percentage': 25.5%
    }
]
```

You can access the items like so:

```
{% for team in teams %}
{{ team['logo'] }}
{{ team['percentage'] }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Tried this, but it doesn't work sadly. I get the same error

Comment: @CarlosX2X the error you are receiving is not related to the dictionary. Flask spawns a new thread with each request, and whatever you are calling is unsafe to call outside the main thread, throwing the exception.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know how to resolve that issue though.

Comment: @CarlosX2X for us to help with that issue we would need to see more of your code. Without seeing the code that is causing the issue, we are unable to provide a solution.